# Dependency convergence error due to three open source projects Apache Drill, Apache Hadoop and Elastic search uses different version of io.netty

Tags: java, netty, dependency-management, nosuchmethoderror

When I ran `mvn clean install` to build the project then I was getting `Dependency convergence error` as you can see below.

```
Dependency convergence error for io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final paths to dependency
 are:
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-com.abc:lmn2-foo:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
    +-org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.3
      +-io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.1
    +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.0
      +-org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.6
        +-io.netty:netty:3.7.0.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.3
    +-io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc:1.8.0
    +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-java-exec:1.8.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7
        +-org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.7
          +-io.netty:netty:3.4.0.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc:1.8.0
    +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-java-exec:1.8.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7
        +-org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.7
          +-io.netty:netty:3.4.0.Final

[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed
 with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final paths to dependency
 are:
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-com.abc:lmn2-foo:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
    +-org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.3
      +-io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.1
    +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.0
      +-org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.6
        +-io.netty:netty:3.7.0.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.3
    +-io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc:1.8.0
    +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-java-exec:1.8.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7
        +-org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.7
          +-io.netty:netty:3.4.0.Final
and
+-com.abc:lmn2-xyz:beta-2.2-20160906_011548
  +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc:1.8.0
    +-org.apache.drill.exec:drill-java-exec:1.8.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7
        +-org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.7
          +-io.netty:netty:3.4.0.Final
]
```

To resolved this issue I put `io.netty:netty:3.10.6.Final` into the `dependency management section`. I thought that it's better to use latest `io.netty:netty:3.10.5.Final` among these open source project. After that it build successfully.

But I get into another issue. Apache Drill start giving me this below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.UniqueName.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOption.<init>(ChannelOption.java:136) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar!/:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOption.valueOf(ChannelOption.java:99) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar!/:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOption.<clinit>(ChannelOption.java:42) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar!/:4.0.27.Final]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient.<init>(BasicClient.java:76) ~[drill-rpc-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClientWithConnection.<init>(BasicClientWithConnection.java:39) ~[drill-rpc-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserClient.<init>(UserClient.java:66) ~[drill-java-exec-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient.connect(DrillClient.java:254) ~[drill-java-exec-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:145) ~[drill-jdbc-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:64) ~[drill-jdbc-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69) ~[drill-jdbc-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126) ~[optiq-avatica-0.9-drill-r20.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72) ~[drill-jdbc-1.8.0.jar!/:1.8.0]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
```

When I extract the `io.netty:netty:3.10.6.Final` jar I found that it does not contain `io.netty.util.UniqueName` class.

I am using Apache Drill, Apache Hadoop and Elastic search in the project but they need specific version of `io.netty`. What to do in this case? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you make something wrong in your dependency for Netty since what you refer now is Netty 4.0 (4.0.27) and not Netty 3.X (io.netty.util.UniqueName is only in Netty 4.0).

```
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOption.<init>(ChannelOption.java:136) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar!/:4.0.27.Final]
```

Try to use the last 3.10 version explicitely (3.10.6).